# Kibana. Data tables. Exclude terms depending on the length

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I'm storing sentences in Elasticsearch.
Example:

```
this is a sentence
this is a second sentence
```

And I want to show a data table with the most used terms in my Kibana 4.3.1, selecting:

```
Metric = count
Split rows
Aggregation = terms
Field = input
Order by = metric count
Order descending. Size 5
```

This is what I'm getting in the table:

```
this     2
is       2
a        2
sentence 2
second   1
```

And I want to remove the short words, with less than 3 chars. In this example, "is" and "a".

How can achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: It works adding a `Exclude Pattern` like this one `[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,3}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works adding this `Exclude Pattern`:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,3}
```